# Socket to communicate with server terminal

Tags: java, sockets

I need to read some data from server, I can get them via terminal and now I need to automate that. Basically I need to send commands (red) and read response (yellow).

[image]

As I understand I can solve the task using Socket. I have implemented class that uses Socket (see it below)

Connection works well.

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(endpoint, port);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

Then I send a command like that:

```
out.println(msg);  // msg = "Gstatus\r\n"
```

After that I expect BufferReader has some data to read

```
int letter;
while(in.ready() && (letter = in.read()) != -1) {
    char c = (char) letter;
    res += c;
}
```

But res is always empty.

Could you please point me what I do wrong? or maybe correct my direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` like this:

Server.java:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10001);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        String command = (String) dataInputStream.readUTF();
        StringBuilder commandLineResult = new StringBuilder();
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                commandLineResult.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(commandLineResult.toString());
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Client.java:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 10001);
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("ls -l");
        System.out.println(dataInputStream.readUTF());

    }
}
```

When the server is running, the client can write the command using its `DataOutputStream`. After that the server can use that command:

The server gets the command from the client socket using the `DataInputStream` and then it passes it into the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` method. that method has an `inputStream` which you can later read from `process` and write to the server's `DataOutputStream`, which sends command line contents to the client socket. After that you can read the results using the client's `DataInputStream`.

Comment: that require servlet to run - unfortunately I can't go that way.